# Applications to tail httpd logs over ssh in windows besides a ssh terminal

Tags: ssh, tail

I'm looking for something like [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) with ssh support or the ability to read from standard input so I can pipe the output of plink.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: You can checkout dbitail: https://github.com/pschweitz/DBITail/wiki And for download:
https://github.com/pschweitz/DBITail/releases

Answer (score 2):

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage-batch

use plink (from the putty suite) to automatically ssh, do a tail command, and logout

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has built a tail program (Tail.exe).  It is part of the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools.

http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

The executable will also function properly on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno about plink, but the way I get baretail to work with ssh is:

> ssh username@domain.com 'tail -f
>   www/logs/logfile.log' >
>   ~/temp/current.log

and then open the current.log file with baretail